# What is the instruction to release updated iPhone application to App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My application just available on the App Store but I found an error, so I fixed it. But from this point I don't see any sort of document about "how to submit updated application to App Store?".

Could you help me with any clear instruction? Which I have to change to make the new version replace the old version and available for user to updated?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the appropriate place for App Store tech support questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the same build process as you did before - build an App Store release binary.

1. Log into iTunes Connect.
2. Click on 'Manage Your Applications'.
3. Click on your application icon.
4. Click on 'Update Application'.
5. Fill out the form and upload the zipped version of the new binary.

Comment: Don't forget to increment the version number in the plist file.

Comment: Thank you, Hunter for a clear instruction, and Thank you bpapa for the key point. iTune Connect will reject new uploading if we don't change the version number in the plist file. :)